# Check if a component has an event listener attached to it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Assuming there's some `<Form>` component. It can be called with a `@cancel` event listener attached to it and if it's the case, I want to show the cancel button that triggers this event. If there's no `@cancel` event, the cancel button should not be visible.

Is there a way to check if a component has event listener attached to it?

Currently I do:

```
<template>
  <form>
    <button v-if="cancelEventPassed" @click="$emit('cancel')">Cancel</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

And call it like this:

```
<Form :cancelEventPassed="true" @cancel="handle_cancel" />
```

either

```
<Form/>
```

Is it possible to achieve this without using any additional property like `cancelEventPassed`?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

When there are listeners attached to a component they are available in the `$listeners` property of the component.

You can use that property to determine if a specific listener is available. For example, here is a computed property that checks for the existence of a `cancel` listener.

```
computed:{
  hasCancelListener(){
    return this.$listeners && this.$listeners.cancel
  }
}
```

And here is an example of that used in a component.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("CustomForm", {
  template:`
    <div>
      <h1>Custom Form</h1>
      <button v-if="hasCancelListener" @click="$emit('cancel')">I have a listener!</button>
    </div>
  `,
  computed:{
    hasCancelListener(){
      return this.$listeners && this.$listeners.cancel
    }
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods:{
    onCancel(){
      alert('canceled')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="app">
  <custom-form @cancel="onCancel"></custom-form>
  <hr>
  <custom-form></custom-form>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that for Vue 2 [event names do not have any automatic case transformation, and kebab case is strongly recommended](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names). This means to check a multi-word listener you cannot use dot notation. For multi-word listeners use `$listeners['my-event']`. Vue 3 contrasts this by [providing automatic case transformation for event names](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html#event-names) (you can always use dot notation with the camelCase name).

Comment: `this._events` will have all the attached events in it.

Answer (score 16):

In Vue 3, the `$listeners` object has been [removed](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/listeners-removed.html#overview). The listeners are now part of the `$attrs` object and **are prefixed with `on`**.

In order to check if a particular listener is present or not in a child component, you can do:

```
computed: {
  hasCancelListener() : boolean {
    return (this.$attrs && this.$attrs.onCancel) as boolean
  }
}
```

The child component is called as:

```
<custom-form @cancel="onCancel"></custom-form>
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work if you are defining custom events in the `emits` property  e.g. with `emits: ['click']` present on your component, `$attrs.onClick` will be undefined. This is a bit of a pain, since it means you can't seem to check if a listener exists for a custom event.

Comment: @AdamReis Have you found a solution for this? (checking if a listener exists for a custom event)

Comment: `useAttrs()` does not show bound event listeners defined by `defineEmits`, that's correct. However, if you instead define an optional prop with `const props = defineProps<...>` that is prefixed with `on` (e. g. `onClear?: () => void`) you can check if it exists with `!!props.onClear`. This works because event listeners are basically the same as props with some syntactic sugar. It even works with Volar.

Answer (score 8):

Since [@prerak-sola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4350275/prerak-sola)'s solution doesn't work if you're defining emits like this (as noted by 
[Adam Reis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4687844/adam-reis)):

```js
const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: 'click', v: MouseEvent): void;
  (e: 'update:modelValue', v: MouseEvent): void;
}>();
```

I figured out, since vue converts all props to an object and just adds a prefix `on` before each event-name, you can just check if the property (the event listener) is defined in the `vnode`:

```js
const hasClickEventListener = computed(() => !!getCurrentInstance()?.vnode.props?.onClick);
const hasModelValueUpdateListener = computed(() => !!getCurrentInstance()?.vnode.props?.['onUpdate:modelValue']);
```

I, however, couldn't find anything about this in the official documentation (and it's much more difficult than using `useAttrs`). So use with caution.

Comment: Using `getCurrentInstance()` was the only solution working for us (using Vue 3.3.4). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## This example for Vue 3

```
this.$attrs.onCancel
```

### Explanation

Vue 3 has removed the `$listeners` object instead listener will be parted from the `$attrs` object with the `on..` prefix.

### Reference

https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/listeners-removed.html#overview

Answer (score 1):

### In Vue 3

```
const thisInstance = getCurrentInstance();

const hasTaskClickedListener = computed(() => {
  if (!thisInstance) return null;

  return thisInstance.attrs?.onClicked;
});
```

explainations:

- `this` is same like `getCurrentInstance()` in vue 3
- listeners object was changing by attrs with prefix "on" like `onClick`, `onDelete` and so on
- put `getCurrentInstance()` always on setup script unless you will got always null (the value when vue can't see their instance)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if listener exists like that:
`this._events['listener-name']`

Answer (score 0):

If you're here looking for Vue 3 `script setup` or `setup function` solution, you can check the `attrs` key in `getCurrentInstance` function

```html
<template>
  <form>
    <button @click="$emit('cancel')">Cancel</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

```html
<custom-form @cancel="onCancel"></custom-form>
```

```js
onMounted(() => {
  const instance = getCurrentInstance() // only available inside lifecycle hooks
  console.log(instance?.attrs?.onCancel)
})
```

Comment: Probably easier to use `useAttrs`

https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#useslots-useattrs

Comment: @floodlitworld as already said multiple times here, `useAttrs` wont't work as they are not exposed there in case you use events in `defineEmits`

Answer (score 0):

#### Vue 2.7 script setup example

```
import {useListeners, computed} from 'vue';

const listeners = useListeners();
const hasCancelListener= computed(() => {
    return typeof listeners['cancel'] !== 'undefined';
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73955732/3282496) from @abdul-aziz-al-basyir .
In Vue 3, use `attrs` to replace `emit` and `listeners`

```
<script setup>
const attrs = useAttrs()
const cancelEventPassed = computed(() => {
  return !!attrs.onCancel
})
function toCancel() {
  attrs.onCancel()
}
</script>
<template>
  <form>
    <button v-if="cancelEventPassed" @click="toCancel">Cancel</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

```js
<Form @cancel="handle_cancel" />
```