# Vue 3 check if emit is present

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm wondering if there are any changes to know if certain emit was passed to vue component using composition api

Component A

```js
  <Component @on-before-add="doSomeAction" />
```

Component B

```js
  <Component />
```

```js
<script setup>
const emit = defineEmits(['onBeforeAdd'])

const action = () => {
  if (true === true) {
    emit('onBeforeAdd')
  }
}

</script>
```

I want to trigger emit only if it's passed. Solution to current code would be passing another prop, like `shouldEmit: Boolean`

```js
  if (props.shouldEmit) {
    emit('onBeforeAdd') // would work, but requires extra prop
  }
```

```js
  if (emit.onBeforeAdd) {
    emit('onBeforeAdd') // ideally needs something like this
  }
```

Example with context:
Product card component with 'add to cart' and 'change quantity' shared logic. When used on catalog pages, it might open "detailed" modal (some products have that, some not) instead of adding to cart. When modal is already opened, no need in opening detailed modal one more time, adding directly to cart.

onBeforeAdd is calling modal set which is shared logic with catalog product card

```js
const handleAddToCart = () => {
  if (!currentAddress.value) {
    ui.setModal({ name: 'address' })
    return
  } else if (props.shouldEmit && props.product.open_item_page_to_add) {
    emit('onBeforeAdd')
    // a.k.a ui.setModal({ name: 'product', id })
    return
  }

  cartStore.addToCart(props.product)
}

const handleQuantityChange = (n: number) => {
  if (n === 0) {
    cartStore.removeFromCart(props.product.id)
  } else {
    cartStore.changeQuantity({ id: props.product.id, quantity: n })
  }
}
```

Pattern comes from react architecture when callbacks are passed as props, i.e.

```js
const component = ({ onCallback }) => { 
  const action = () => {
    onCallback && onCallback()
  }

  return <button onClick={action} />
}
```

Comment: I don't see the case you want to do that. It's not responsibility of the Child Component to check if Parent is listening to some event. But never the less this is interesting case. Are you using `setup` hook or `<script setup>`?

Comment: @AdamOrłowski added context, It's kind of edge case. I'm using script setup. Basically under normal conditions I might emit every time, and if nothing has been passed, it won't do anything and throw no errors. But there is return logic to prevent further code execution

Comment: I don't see [user20278560](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20278560/user20278560)'s answer was working. Here are the solutions I found. Vue3, https://stackoverflow.com/a/67967566/1939549 Vue2, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46708440/1939549

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76208995/14085119

```
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue';

const thisInstance = getCurrentInstance();

const emit = defineEmits(['onBeforeAdd'])

if (thisInstance?.vnode?.props?.onBeforeAdd) {
  emit('onBeforeAdd') 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I came up with this solution.

```
if (emit.listener.addToCart && props.product.id === data.id) {
  emit('onBeforeAdd')
} else if (emit.listener.changeQuantity && props.product.id === data.id) {
  emit('onBeforeAdd')
} else {
  emit.listener.setModal({ name: 'modal', id: props.product.id })
}
```

As you can see, you can handle the cases in a separate ways, not only by the event name, but also by conditions.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I'm `getting emit.listener` = undefined